# Por que no puedo consultar el updated_at y created_at_degree en Django con postgresql?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, consultar

Tengo este modelo:

```
class certificadosT(models.Model):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

En views tengo este codigo:

```
certificados = certificadosT.objects.all()
for certificado in certificados:
    print("updated______"+certificado.updated_at)
```

Pero en el print no me imprime nada, me imprime los demás campos, menos el de creado y actualizado.
Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Podrias intentar probar este código en consola? Pregunta de seguimiento: Si tienes datos guardados en base de datos para este modelo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay que convertir el `certificado.updated_at` a string de esta forma `str(certificado.updated_at)`, y todo quedaría así `print("updated______"+str(certificado.updated_at))`